# ParallelTable and plotting result of own define funtion

Tags: plotting, parallelization

I define function which return a list of numbers

```
KSmoothTest[vy_, b_] := Block[{n, res, i, j, weights},
   n = Length[vy];
   weights = Table[K[i/b], {i, 0, Length[vy] - 1}];
   Table[Sum[weights[[Abs[i - j] + 1]]*vy[[j]], {j, 1, n}]/
     Sum[weights[[Abs[i - j] + 1]], {j, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}]
   ];
```

I want run this code

```
Table[ListLinePlot[KSmoothTest[RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 10], 9]], {i, 1, 10}]
```

in parallel using ParallelTable.
I try this

```
ParallelTable[ListLinePlot[KSmoothTest[RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 10], 9]], {i, 1, 10}]
```

but Mathematica return graphics like this:

[image]

What is wrong? Why Mathematica return empty graphic?
PS: sory for my english, i am not strong in it

**EDIT:**
K[t_]:=1.078222*Exp[-(t^2/0.273800)];

Comment: Two questions:- What is K?  and why are you using Block (Rather than Module)?

Comment: _K is a default generic name for a summation index in a symbolic sum._ I'm not sure you mean that :)

Comment: oh, fogot for this funtion. Please read now

Comment: really? I don't see definition of this symbol in documentation centre

Comment: `?K` returns what I wrote above. And it's in black, so it's built-in :)

Comment: It is the problem, it works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a built-in symbol `K` in your `KSmoothTest` function. `K` appears black and

```
?K
```

returns

> K is a default generic name for a summation index in a symbolic sum.

Thus by turning `K` into `k` you have:

```
k[t_] := 1.078222*Exp[-(t^2/0.273800)];
KSmoothTest[vy_, b_] := Block[{n, weights}, n = Length[vy];
  weights = Table[k[i/b], {i, 0, Length[vy] - 1}];
  Table[Sum[weights[[Abs[i - j] + 1]]*vy[[j]], {j, 1, n}]/
    Sum[weights[[Abs[i - j] + 1]], {j, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}]];

ParallelTable[ ListLinePlot[KSmoothTest[RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 10], 9]], {j, 1, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: One question remains.., why does it work with `Table` and not `ParellelTable`.

Comment: Thank for help. I made bad mistake)

Comment: @molekyla777 We all did :)